# How to show featured post first, then separate loop for other posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, featured-post

I have followed the [instructions from the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_2) for multiple loops, but am having problems.

I have a category called 'Featured' and a tag called 'Canada 2017' which are the posts I would like to display on the page. My code below, with comments for what I have tried:

```
<?php 

// Attempting to show featured first: the array pulls one post from the 'Featured' category with the relevant tag. This works correctl

$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name' => 'featured',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'tag_slug__in' => get_the_title() ) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<!-- Code to display featured post with relevant formatting goes here -->

<?php

// This ends the first loop

endwhile; ?>

<?php 

// The query for standard posts: this is supposed to check posts for the relevant tag. This loop worked correctly before I added the loop for featured posts

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'tag_slug__in' => get_the_title(), 
            'posts_per_page' => -1 
            ) );

// The loop to display these posts according to the query

if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); 

// This line is from the Codex, and is supposed to prevent duplication of the featured post. I'm unsure if this is implemented correctly?

    if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<!-- Formatting for regular posts -->

<?php

    // Ending second loop

    endwhile;

    endif;

?>
```

I'd love any help with getting both loops working!

Comment: Can you tell what's not working?  What is happening that shouldn't or what isn't happening that should.

Comment: I did in the //comments within the code, although admittedly it's not that clear looking back over it, apologies.

The first loop successfully pulls in the 'featured' post from the correct category, but the second loop doesn't pull any posts in at all. The second loop worked correctly by itself before the featured' loop was added.

Comment: Try: if ( $post -> ID != $do_not_duplicate )  in the 2nd part of your code.

Comment: I tried that change - now neither loop pulls any post. Do you recommend removing 'continue;' from after that piece of code, or should that be kept?

Comment: is this the exact code you're using?  Because this code doesn't actually return anything for the 2nd part.  Can you please upload your true code?  There are a couple things missing here..

Comment: That's exactly my issue. The second loop doesn't work when combined with the first, but it works if you use it by itself.

Comment: So this is the exact code

Answer (score 0):

You've got a whole lot of problems here.  First you're asking for Tag_slug__in, but providing a title, secondly tag_slug__in accepts an array (I'm not sure it will work with a string).  Both issues will cause problems because titles are not slugs and arrays are not strings..  Maybe just use "tag"?  But what if page title doesn't equal a slug? Then you have an error and no error message to say what happened. (which i believe is what is happening here.)  Or you have more than one featured post?

You have 2 custom queries but you're not reseting post data in either of them.

I asked to see the rest of your code, because I don't know what kind of page this is on to relate to the "get_the_title()" reference in your args  .  Is this is an archive, template, category, or taxonomy page etc.

Here is a code sample to try.  I've commented out your tag_slug__in from both your queries.  I've added post resets, I've added an actual return of content for you in each.

```
<?php 

// Attempting to show featured first: the array pulls one post from the 'Featured' category with the relevant tag. This works correctly

$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name' => 'featured',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            //'tag_slug__in' => get_the_title() 
            ) 
            );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<!-- Code to display featured post with relevant formatting goes here -->
echo 'My Featured Post: '. get_the_title().'<br><hr><br>';
<?php

// This ends the first loop

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php 

// The query for standard posts: this is supposed to check posts for the relevant tag. This loop worked correctly before I added the loop for featured posts

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            //'tag_slug__in' => get_the_title(), 
            'posts_per_page' => -1 
            ) 
            );

// The loop to display these posts according to the query

if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); 

// This line is from the Codex, and is supposed to prevent duplication of the featured post. I'm unsure if this is implemented correctly?

    if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<!-- Formatting for regular posts -->
echo 'Not a Featured Post: '. get_the_title().'<br>';
<?php

    // Ending second loop

    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, apologies for not replying. I abandoned this aspect of my theme in the end. But thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: No worries.  Can you mark as answered to close the question?  Check mark to the left...